# Kusto - Conver table data to time series chart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a Kusto table result with different package sizes released for 2 types of VM´s on daily basis. On the table I have the 3 columns - 1) Timestamp, 2) VM Type (Win & Linux split), 3) Package size in MB.

Could you please tell me how do I create a graph that will have Y axis as timestamp, x axis as Package size and with the line representing the package size for VM (Win & Linux) Basically it will appear as 2 lines on the graph showing the package sizes for diff days.

I tried with visual type - line chart option but it does not work with any combination of X and Y axis in Data column. I am not sure if the render time chart will work . Could you pls provide any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*If* I understood your description correctly, you could try something like this, assuming `Timestamp` is a `datetime` column:

```
TableName
| summarize take_any(PackageSize) by VmType, bin(Timestamp, 1d)
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks. it gives me message -- 
Error 
 bin(): argument #1 - invalid data type: string

Comment: If the data in the `Timestamp` column represents datetime values, you should have it typed as `datetime` and not `string` when you define the table. For now, you can try converting it at query runtime by calling `todatetime(Timestamp)`, assuming its values are in a parsable format. Though doing this at query runtime is not efficient.

Comment: Could you give me an example please. I use the below Query . and it says - Error 
 bin(): argument #1 - invalid data type: string. Not sre where I am going wrong
```
T
| where stepName contains "PackageSize"
| parse Data with Timestamp:datetime " " *
| extend Timestamp = format_datetime(Timestamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm]')
| parse Data with * "VmType=" VmType
| parse Data with * "PackageSize=" PackageSize
| summarize take_any(VmType), take_any(PackageSize) by Timestamp
| summarize take_any(PackageSize) by VmType, bin(Timestamp, 1d)
| render timechart```